# Simulate a Logout with HttpSessionListener

Tags: session, servlets, jakarta-ee

I have a application which has a `logout.html` (this is provided by third party) which invalidates the `SSO`(Siteminder) session:

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="pragma"            content="no-cache">
    <meta http-equiv="expires"           content="Fri, 5 Sep 1980 08:00:00 GMT">
    <meta http-equiv="cache-control" content="no-cache">
</head>
</html>
```

- Now when my application's `session` expires I want to invalidate the `SSO session` as well.
- My idea was to add a session-destroyed listener, and within this listener somehow "simulate" the logout.html's content.

  Is this somehow possible?